# Migrate Private Files: FILE_EXISTS_REUSE still duplicate files

Tags: files, migrations

I'm trying to migrate private files (file migration), the problem is even I set file_replace to 'FILE_EXISTS_REUSE' the files are still duplicated (it adds _1 or _2, and so on.). Here is my mapping:

```
    $this->addFieldMapping('file_replace')
         ->defaultValue('FILE_EXISTS_REUSE');
    $this->addFieldMapping('preserve_files')
       ->defaultValue(FALSE);
```

Please help!

Comment: Are you sure you should not use `$this->addFieldMapping('file_replace')->defaultValue(FILE_EXISTS_REUSE);`?

Comment: I've already tried that, but still no good.

Answer (score 1):

This solved it for me.  The documentation at [this link](https://www.drupal.org/node/1540106) has been updated to show that you need to use the class prefix:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('preserve_files')
  ->defaultValue(1);

$this->addFieldMapping('file_replace')
  ->defaultValue(MigrateFile::FILE_EXISTS_REUSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('field_name', 'field_name');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_name:file_replace')->defaultValue(MigrateFile::FILE_EXISTS_REUSE);
```